# Pass (La)TeX-Length as function argument using pythontex

Tags: python

I'm trying to pass a LaTeX-Length (`\textwidth`) to a python function specified in an `pyblock`-environment provided by the `pythontex`-package. Running pythontex gives me an error message, that does not provide any help to me:

```
This is PythonTeX v0.12

----  Messages for py:default:default  ----
* PythonTeX stderr - error on line 10:
    File "<outputdir>/py_default_default.py", line 65
      print(pytex.formatter(printtexlength(\textwidth )))
                                                        ^
  SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

--------------------------------------------------
PythonTeX:  minimal - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Has anybody an idea what is going wrong here, or how can I pass a LaTeX-Length to a python-function?

Here is a minimal-example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
def printtexlength(length):
    print('Length ist %f' % length)
\end{pycode}
\newcommand{\printlength}[1]{\py{printtexlength(#1)}}
%\py{printtexlength(\textwidth)} % This although fails with same error message
\printlength{\textwidth}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that the `pythontex` commands don't expand their arguments, so Python receives the literal string `\textwidth` and doesn't know what to do with it. egreg's solution expands `\textwidth` to avoid this. The next version of `pythontex` (beta on GitHub in a few days) has built-in utilities for passing contextual information like page dimensions to the Python side, as well as conversion functions for going from pt to in, cm, and mm.  This can be used to make figures automatically adjust to page dimensions, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\py` doesn't accept this, but only an explicit number. Here's a possibly working version, where the dimension is expanded to a number before passing it to `\py`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{pythontex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printlength}[1]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\py{printtexlength(\strip@pt\dimexpr#1\relax)}}\x}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
def printtexlength(length):
    print('Length is %f' % length)
\end{pycode}
\printlength{\textwidth}

\printlength{1in}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know enough Python to understand why `None` appears.

Thanks to G. Poore, here's the correct version of the function:

```
\begin{pycode}
def printtexlength(length):
    return 'Length is %f' % length
\end{pycode}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\py` macro automatically prints a string version of whatever it is given (it can be given numbers, the names of existing Python variables, quoted strings, or any other valid Python code...it just doesn't expand its argument).  The `print()` in `printtexlength()` is not needed.  What is happening is that `printtexlength()` prints the desired value, and then `\py` prints the return value of the function, which is `None`.  Instead, `printtexlength()` should be `return 'Length is %f' % length`.  Then only the desired text will be printed.