# Pgfplots: pass to raw gnuplot string unitless plot width and height

Tags: pgfplots

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group size=1 by 4,
    vertical sep=0.1in,
  },
  scale only axis,
  width=\columnwidth-0.5in-0.09in,
  domain=-0.482362:0.035276,
  xmin=-0.495, xmax=0.0352762,
]
\nextgroupplot[
  height=0.8in,
  ymin=-0.9, ymax=4.9,
]
  \addplot
    gnuplot[id=plot1, raw gnuplot]
      {plot '< plotpointreduce -t 0.0175 --max-dist 0.1
         --width 2.897 --height 0.8
         --xrange \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin} \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}
         --yrange \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin} \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}
         --x-column delta --y-column v_12 data_fem_0.dat' u 'delta':'v_12'}
    ;
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I pass the specified values of the axis width(\columnwidth-0.5in-0.09in) and height (0.8in) in the `groupplot` and `\nextgroupplot` options to my raw gnuplot string similar to `--xrange` and `--yrange`?

The script `plotpointreduce` expects unitless floats for `--width` and `--height`, the ratio is only considered.

**Update:**

I have changed the call to:

```
  \addplot
    gnuplot[id=plot1, raw gnuplot]
      {plot '< plotpointreduce -t 0.0175 --max-dist 0.1
         --width  \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}
         --height \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/height}
         --xrange \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin} \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}
         --yrange \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin} \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}
         --x-column delta --y-column v_12 data_fem_0.dat' u 'delta':'v_12'}
    ;
```

However, `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}` returns `\columnwidth -0.5in-0.09in`.
How can I convert this to the actual value in `inch`?

I have placed the lengthy 'home-baked' script `plotpointreduce` on https://gist.github.com/Hotschke/afdcd9efabe385c641a6.

**Update II**

```
     --width  \the\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}
```

`\the` will expand columnwidth.

My script still complains `plotpointreduce: error: argument -w/--width: invalid float value: '345.0pt-0.5in-0.09in'`

So I guess my question is simply about expanding this expression. What is the shortest way to do it?

Comment: So what unit are the `--width` and `--height` arguments in?

Comment: The plot ratio is actually only important, not the units. You can pass them in all units you like.

Comment: I can't really get your MWE to run, but it seems like the only problem is, that you can not use `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}` because it adds a pt to the end. Right?

Comment: Can you provide the script file?

Comment: I will extend my script to accept units, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @sergej: see the gist link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further internet search I could figure it out. I don't know if it's the most reliable way of doing it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\makeatletter
\def\Printdimensionless#1{\strip@pt \dimexpr (#1)\relax}
\makeatother
% For convenience
\newcommand{\pwidth}{\Printdimensionless{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}} } % trailing space important
\newcommand{\pheight}{\Printdimensionless{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/height}} }
\newcommand{\pxrange}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin} \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax} }
\newcommand{\pyrange}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin} \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax} }
\begin{filecontents}{data_fem_0.dat}
id   delta      E_1        E_2        v_12       v_21       G_12     err         porosity  E_cs_1_norm  E_cs_2_norm
049  -0.48      2.6891     2.9098     0.33942    0.36728    1.1087   0.010752    0.914955  0.89481      0.968249
047  -0.46      0.014184   0.1251     -0.3269    -2.8832    0.71385  0.0011567   0.88558   0.00343525   0.0302982
\end{filecontents} % inserts '%' comment lines
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group size=1 by 2,
    vertical sep=0.1in,
  },
  scale only axis,
  width=\columnwidth-0.5in,
  domain=-0.482362:0.035276,
  xmin=-0.495, xmax=0.0352762,
]
\nextgroupplot[
  height=0.8in,
  ymin=-0.9, ymax=4.9,
]
  \addplot
    gnuplot[id=poisson12, raw gnuplot]
      {set datafile commentschars '#\%';
          \addplot
gnuplot[id=young1, raw gnuplot]
  {plot '< plotpointreduce -t 0.0
    --width  \pwidth --height \pheight
    --xrange \pxrange --yrange \pyrange
     -x delta -y E_cs_1_norm ./data_fem_0.dat' u 'delta':'v_12'}; 'delta':'v_12'}
    ;
\nextgroupplot[
  height=0.8in,
  ytick={0,0.5,1},
  ymin=0, ymax=1,
]
  \addplot
    gnuplot[id=young1, raw gnuplot]
      {set datafile commentschars '#\%';
        plot '< plotpointreduce -t 0.0
         --width  \pwidth --height \pheight
         --xrange \pxrange --yrange \pyrange
         -x delta -y E_cs_1_norm ./data_fem_0.dat' u 'delta':'E_cs_1_norm'};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Helpful answers:

- [Pass (La)TeX-Length as function argument using pythontex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156155/pass-latex-length-as-function-argument-using-pythontex)
- [Is there a command to convert cm to bp?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22701/is-there-a-command-to-convert-cm-to-bp)
- [Why we used \number in Latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241057/why-we-used-number-in-latex)
- [Convert dimension to integer number of mm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223740/convert-dimension-to-integer-number-of-mm)